# Updating/Appending to an existing XML

Tags: c#, xml, c++-cli, append

I'm having a problem updating an existing XML but i'm not getting any errors. The aim of the function is to check if the file exists if it does exist then i want the new values to be appended to the end of the existing XML.

The function checks the existing XMLs without any problems and if it doesn't find the XML that works perfectly aswell but when the file does exist it isnt appending the new information to the end. Please can someone help me

The code below is the part of the function that checks the existing files and attempts to update the file.

```
void HashMe::SaveHashButton()
{
    try
    {
        array<String^>^ Available = gcnew array<String^>(100);
        Available = IO::Directory::GetFiles("E:\\XML Folder\\");
        String^ TextBoxText = textBox1->Text->ToString();

        for(int x = 0; x < Available->Length; x++)
        {
            String^ Current = Available[x];
            String^ NoExtension = IO::Path::GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Current);

            if(TextBoxText == NoExtension)
            {
                XmlDocument^ XmlDoc = gcnew XmlDocument();
                XmlDoc->Load(Current);

                XmlDoc->CreateElement("Project");
                XmlDoc->CreateAttribute("Name", textBox1->Text->ToString());

                XmlDoc->CreateElement("TestCycle");
                XmlDoc->CreateAttribute("Number", textBox2->Text->ToString());

                for (int x = 0; x < listBox2->Items->Count; ++x)
                {
                    String^ FileName = listBox2->Items[x]->ToString();
                    String^ Hash = listBox3->Items[x]->ToString();

                    XmlDoc->CreateElement("FileName");
                    XmlDoc->CreateAttribute("FileName", FileName);

                    XmlDoc->CreateElement("HashCode");
                    XmlDoc->CreateAttribute("HashCode", Hash);
                }
                XmlDoc->AppendChild(

                XmlDoc->Save(Current);
                return;
            }
        }
```

The output for creating a brand new XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Name="d">
    <TestCycle Number="1">
        <FileName>E:\XML Folder\c.xml</FileName>
        <HashCode>FC-8B-4D-EF-F6-21-C8-7A-1B-8C-40-BE-AC-7E-1E-5B</HashCode>
    </TestCycle>
</Project>
```

So if the update is successful i would like the updated XML to look like this for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Name="d">
    <TestCycle Number="1">
        <FileName>E:\XML Folder\c.xml</FileName>
        <HashCode>FC-8B-4D-EF-F6-21-C8-7A-1B-8C-40-BE-AC-7E-1E-5B</HashCode>
    </TestCycle>
</Project>
<Project Name="This is the appended new information">
    <TestCycle Number="99">
        <FileName>E:\XML Folder\c.xml</FileName>
        <HashCode>FC-8B-4D-EF-F6-21-C8-7A-1B-8C-40-BE-AC-7E-1E-5B</HashCode>
        <FileName>E:\XML Folder\c.xml</FileName>
        <HashCode>FC-8B-4D-EF-F6-21-C8-7A-1B-8C-40-BE-AC-7E-1E-5B</HashCode>
        <FileName>E:\XML Folder\c.xml</FileName>
        <HashCode>FC-8B-4D-EF-F6-21-C8-7A-1B-8C-40-BE-AC-7E-1E-5B</HashCode>
        <FileName>E:\XML Folder\c.xml</FileName>
        <HashCode>FC-8B-4D-EF-F6-21-C8-7A-1B-8C-40-BE-AC-7E-1E-5B</HashCode>
    </TestCycle>
</Project>
```

Please someone help me :(

Comment: Just curious, why are you using C++/CLI for this task?

Comment: I wasn't sure how else to do it, are u referring to using a library rather? I've never used a library before I'm still quite new to coding and visual studio

Comment: No, I meant why choose C++/CLI instead of C# on one side or plain C++ (with some XML library) on the other. You won't find many examples for C++/CLI on the net, IntelliSense in Visual Studio doesn't work and you have to remember to put `^`s everywhere.

Comment: to be honest I'm not really sure. When i first started using VS 2-3months ago i didn't really realise how similar the two languages are. When i learnt C++ it was all done console based so i only really learnt the logic behind programming. So when i started with this application i started in C++/CLI not really understanding what i was doing. After this i will diffinately be trying C# i'd really like to be able to use WPF and learn XAML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
XmlDocument^ XmlDoc = gcnew XmlDocument();
XmlDoc->Load("projects.xml");

XmlElement^ NewProject = XmlDoc->CreateElement("Project");
NewProject->SetAttribute("Name", "This is the appended new information");
XmlDoc->DocumentElement->AppendChild(NewProject);

XmlElement^ NewTestCycle = XmlDoc->CreateElement("TestCycle");
NewProject->SetAttribute("Number", "99");
NewProject->AppendChild(NewTestCycle);

for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x)
{
    String^ FileName = "E:\\XML Folder\\c.xml";
    String^ Hash = "FC-8B-4D-EF-F6-21-C8-7A-1B-8C-40-BE-AC-7E-1E-5B";

    XmlElement^ NewFileName = XmlDoc->CreateElement("FileName");
    NewFileName->SetAttribute("FileName", FileName);
    NewTestCycle->AppendChild(NewFileName);

    XmlElement^ NewHashCode = XmlDoc->CreateElement("HashCode");
    NewHashCode->SetAttribute("HashCode", Hash);
    NewTestCycle->AppendChild(NewHashCode);
}

XmlDoc->Save("new projects.xml");
```

Also, if I understand the XML correctly, better structure would be something like the following, so that it's obvious that the `<FileName>` and `<HashCode>` belong together.

```
<File>
  <FileName>E:\XML Folder\c.xml</FileName>
  <HashCode>FC-8B-4D-EF-F6-21-C8-7A-1B-8C-40-BE-AC-7E-1E-5B</HashCode>
</File>
```

Comment: Hey svick. That worked perfectly thank you! When creating the XML for the first time i was using WriteString("Some Value"). But since XmlDocument() doesn't seem to have this function I will convert it to rather work how XmlDocument works. For comparison purposes I take it that it would be easier to use attributes than a string?

Comment: When you are creating the document, you can create the root element the same way as any other element and then do `XmlDoc->AppendChild(RootElement)`. I don't understand what you mean by attributes or string.

Comment: I'm using the XmlWriter class for creating the non existing Xml files and when i was assigning the filename or hashcodes i was doing so like this: Writer->WriteStartElement("HashCode"); Writer->WriteString(Hash); Rather than using Writer->WriteAttributeString. So the syntax when viewing the xml looked different from when it was first created. If that makes sense

Comment: Yeah, makes sense now. Yeah, using an attribute for the hash would work too.